Ida Pro python disconnect debugger and imeddietly connect next one in same script
My current script for connecting to debugger is this, however if there's a debugger is already running then it gets disconnected, but new one does not start, have to run script second time to connect.
Problem is if i add time.sleep(3) it does not just adds wait to the script it also puts ida to sleep same as idc.qsleep(3) so debugger does not exit until 3 seconds wait.
import ida_idd, ida_dbg, time

if ida_dbg.is_debugger_on():
    print("Debugger already running.")
    print("disconnected successfully" if ida_dbg.exit_process() else 'failed to disconnect')
    time.sleep(3)

process_name = "my_process_name"
pis = ida_idd.procinfo_vec_t()
count = ida_dbg.get_processes(pis)

#print(f"Found {count}")
for p in pis:
    #print(f"{p.pid}: {p.name}")
    if process_name in p.name:
        #print(f"Attaching to process {p.name}")
        ida_dbg.attach_process(p.pid)
        break


isn't that exit_process debugger api asynchronous?

@AliRizvi-Santiago what exactly this means? Is there way to introduce wait to make sure it exits before trying to connect again?
